# ¿Se puede publicar link de descarga de códigos?

Tags: discusión

Me preguntaba si está permitido colocar links para descargar código en las preguntas/respuestas como aporte adicional la solución.

Lo que pasa es que sería bueno que los que respondemos a las preguntas además de publicar la solución, tambien pudieramos publicar un link del "código fuente de un ejemplo completo" para que el que este interesado pueda descargarlo.

**¿Está permitido?**

Answer (score 2):

Sí, está permitido.

Repasemos lo importante: **una respuesta debe tener todo el código necesario para responder a la pregunta**. Las partes relevantes del código que aportan a la solución tienen que estar en el cuerpo de la publicación... A todos nos gusta leer una respuesta completa, sin tener que abrir un enlace para ver de qué se trata.

Las respuestas no son para el autor de la pregunta, sino para generar una base de conocimientos que le aporte valor a todos los que la lean.

Pero **cuando hay más código que es irrelevante para la respuesta**, que sólo completa las partes obvias y accesorias del código, el cual generaría más ruido que contenido de calidad, ahí perfectamente podría estar en un recurso externo... Pensemos que la web externa podría dejar de estar accesible en el futuro. Desde el ideal, la respuesta tendría el mismo valor con o sin el enlace.

Ahora bien, una cosa es lo que está permitido y otra **lo que es bien recibido por la comunidad** (lo que a su vez podría variar entre etiquetas). Se pueden revisar otras preguntas de la misma etiqueta para ver de qué modo la comunidad suele compartir recursos externos.
<sup>* [Aporte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1780/se-puede-publicar-link-de-descarga-de-c%C3%B3digos/1781?noredirect=1#comment5053_1781) de [Rubén](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/65/rub%C3%A9n)</sup>

Se suele recomendar que esos enlaces a recursos externos estén **sobre sitios reconocidos**. A muchos no les va a gustar entrar en una página personal para bajar el código, o tener que dejar rastro de su usuario de Google o facebook antes de poder descargarlo. Existen muchos compiladores online, ampliamente reconocidos, que permiten leer el código completo, y ejecutarlo en la misma web, sin iniciar sesión en ninguna cuenta.

Para estos casos, yo siempre recomiendo páginas como [ideone](http://ideone.com/), [rextester](http://rextester.com/), [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm), etc.

Adicionalmente, es bueno comentar a dónde dirige el enlace (ejemplo: "*enlace descarga proyecto en EstaWeb.com*") y cuidar que no sea una descarga directa del archivo.
<sup>* [Aporte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1780/se-puede-publicar-link-de-descarga-de-c%C3%B3digos/1781?noredirect=1#comment5051_1781) de [JuankGlezz](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6635/juankglezz)</sup>

Comment: y que tal un archivo comprimido publico en dropbox

Comment: @Jorny es valido también, pero lo mejor es un compilador online ya que te evitas la molestia de tener que abrir editor de texto y ejecutar para depuración. Como adicional para la respuesta de mariano es bueno comentar a donde dirige el enlace es decir (enlace descarga proyecto - Dropbox) y cuidar que no sea una descarga directa del archivo, por otro lado agrego este enlace a una pagina donde hay una compilacion de IDEs online https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

Comment: @Jorny No está prohibido, pero personalmente no lo recomendaría. Un enlace a Dropbox claramente puede romperse en el futuro. Además, no recomendaría agregar un archivo binario que la mayoría no esté dispuesto a descargar. Las respuestas no son para el autor de la pregunta, sino para generar una base de conocimientos que le aporte valor a todos los que lo leen.

Comment: Cabría aclarar que una cosa es lo que está permitido y otra que lo es bien recibido por la comunidad (lo que a su vez podría variar entre etiquetas ) (: